# How to deploy the Consul client on K8s with custom config.yaml?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, microservices, consul

I am trying to deploy the Consul client on a k8s cluster ( the Consul server is on a docker swarm cluster). I want to use a config.yaml (mentioned in https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/installation/deployment-configurations/servers-outside-kubernetes) to set up the configuration. I found a Helm Chart Configuration page (https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/helm#client) and a Configuration page (https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#config_key_reference). What is the difference between them?  It seems that I need to refer to the Helm Chart Configuration page since I am working on the k8s. However, on the Helm Chart Configuration page, I can not find how to set up something like node_name, data_dir, client_addr, bind_addr, advertise_addr. Besides, I also need to set  verify_incoming, encrypt, verify_outgoing, verify_server_hostname. For ca_file, cert_file, and key_file, I assume that cert_file  is for caCert (in Helm Chart Configuration), key_file is for caKey, and I am not sure what the ca_file stand for.

k8s version:
Server Version:v1.22.4
There ate four servers in the cluster.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please describe what and how did you create your cluster. Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Answer (score 0):

> I can not find how to set up something like node_name, data_dir, client_addr, bind_addr, advertise_addr. Besides, I also need to set verify_incoming, encrypt, verify_outgoing, verify_server_hostname. For ca_file, cert_file, and key_file, I assume that cert_file is for caCert

Most of these parameters are specified by the Helm chart when deploying the Consul client or server pods. Is there a particular reason that you need to override these particular settings?

With that said, you can use [`server.extraConfig`](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/helm#v-server-extraconfig) and [`client.extraConfig`](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/helm#v-client-extraconfig) to provide additional configuration parameters to the server and client agents. Normally you would only specify parameters that are not already specified by deployments created by the Helm chart.